# Проверка данных из массива

Tags: php

Как правильно сделать проверку данных из массива? Вот пример как я делаю:

Форма:

```
 <form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter nubmer">
     <input type="submit" value="code" class="button">
 </form>
```

Код PHP:

```
$_POST = $code;
$code = array("CodeOne", "CodeTwo", "CodeThree", "CodeFour");
    if (in_array('', $code)) {
        echo "Nice! Product is verification!";
    } else (in_array('', $code)) {
        echo "Oh, no! Product is not verification!";
    }
```

Comment: если вы хотите присвоить массиву `$code`, всё что пришло из поста , вам нужно делать $code = $_POST, а не наоборот. и что вы хотите сделать вот этим? `$code = array("CodeOne", "CodeTwo", "CodeThree", "CodeFour");`? 
Из примера вы можете получить только `$_POST['code']`

Comment: Хочу сделать так: к примеру у меня в массиве есть "Машина", "Велосипед", "Вертолет", и если я ввожу в форму "Машина" - я получаю true, точнее правильный ответ.

Comment: Так может, правильней дать возможность выбора через селект ?

Comment: @dirk Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно просто удалить пустые значения из массива например так:

```
$code = array_diff($_POST['code'], ['']);
```